# Why isn't asymptote working in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio, asymptote

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\title{}
\author{ }
\date{}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\pdfpagewidth 8.5in
\pdfpageheight 11in

\topmargin 0in
\headheight 0in
\headsep 0in
\textheight 9in
\textwidth 6.5in
\oddsidemargin 0in
\evensidemargin 0in

\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}



\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{{\large Asymptote Test}}
    \end{center} 
    
    % Your LaTeX content
    
    \begin{asy}
    size(5cm);
    draw((0,0)--(1,1));
    \end{asy}
    
\end{document}
```

I have asy.exe installed:

[image: configure TeXstudio]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you so much!

- William

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't get any errors. Nothing pops up except for the title. I will try doing --shell-escape. Thanks, - William.

Comment: I don't see that, all I see in my messages is "Process exited normally" and all I see in Log is Asymptote_Test.tex Warning: file 'Asymptote.Test-1..pdf' not found

Comment: your example works with `pdflatex file`;  `asy file-1.asy`; `pdflatex file`;

Comment: so the above commands should work with `file`  being `Asymptote.Test`

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what you are talking about? From my understanding, my example won't work in TeXstudio but it will work with pdflatex.

Comment: texstudio is just the editor. when you ran pdflatex it will have written a file `Asymptote_Test-1.asy`, run `asy Asymptote_Test-1.asy` and it will make `Asymptote_Test-1.pdf` then run pdflatex again and the diagram will be included

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: how do I run the .asy file? It opens up this window that immediately closes afterward.

Comment: error: could not load module 'plain'

Comment: I actually know nothing about asymtote but your example worked for me, so it's a set-up problem not an error in the document. someone will be able to help

Comment: I have uninstalled everything that has to do with latex because it seems like my compilers are all corrupted.